# What will be the coefficients in expansion of $(1+x)^n$ if $x^k =1$ for some $k<n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What will be the coefficients in expansion of $(1+x)^n$ if $x^k =1$ for some $k<n$?

Is there any faster method of finding the coefficients instead of finding the binomial coefficients and adding the respective values?

Also mention if the same can be found mod some other value.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series this will help. And the additional statement probably states that $n>0$. But this series is a general one. And yeah. Use Latex.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Pascal's triangle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Binomial_expansions) Each row is the coefficients of a binomial expansion. This is a simple way of finding the the coefficients of $(1+x)^n$ for small $n$. Also the sum of the nth row is $2^n$.

Comment: @anubhavjha does this answer your question?